# How to use count and group by for two columns which different clauses in where

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table
Attendance (SessionId, StudentId, IfPresent)

```
S1, Stu001, 1 
S1, Stu002, 1 
S1, Stu003, 1 
S1, Stu004, 1 
S1, Stu005, 1 
S2, Stu001, 1 
S2, Stu002, 0 
S2, Stu065, 1 
S3, Stu003, 0 
.
.
.
```

which basically collects information about students assigned to a particular session and attendance in it.

What I want is a report like this

Attendance_report (SessionId, Total Students, Attendance)

```
S13, 20, 18 
S15, 20, 17 
S56, 40, 28
```

Attendance will come doing a count with IfPresent = 1 in the where clause
Total students will come from a count without any where clause

Comment: Can you provide Some Sample Data

Comment: Added sample data

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? These are different products.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner. Have removed mysql from the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Select SessionId, count(*) as [Total Students],
sum(case when IfPresent = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Attendance 
from Attendance_report
group by SessionId
```

Comment: your Welcome @traveloid

Answer (score 1):

Group by `SessionId` so as to get one result row per session and build the Aggregates (which are a simple count and a sum in your case):

```
select
  sessionid,
  count(*) as total_students,
  sum(ifpresent) as attendance
from attendance
group by sessionid;
```

Comment: The column somehow is not a number so give an operand error but thanks. This will work normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN

Create Table #Attandance (Session_ID NVARCHAR(10),StudentId NVARCHAR(20), IfPresent INT )
INSERT INTO #Attandance
SELECT 'S1', 'Stu001', 1  UNION ALL
SELECT 'S1', 'Stu002', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'S1', 'Stu003', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'S1', 'Stu004', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'S1', 'Stu005', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'S2', 'Stu001', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'S2', 'Stu002', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 'S2', 'Stu065', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'S3', 'Stu003', 0 


SELECT Session_ID,COUNT(*)[Total Students], 
SUM(IfPresent)from #Attandance
GROUP BY Session_ID

ROLLBACK TRAN
```